# Actitvity going to freez state

Tags: android

I am launching activity on some running android app using adb command (first launch any android app than using adb command start activity).

Activity starts but after the finish it freezes the previous running application.

```
adb command:
adb shell am start -n com.example.a/com.example.a.MainActivity`enter code here`
```

Java Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent i = new Intent("com.ex.intentdemo.Action_myown");
        startActivity(i);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try onPause(); instead of finish();,because finish(); ends the Activity. See the android lifecycle.But still to tell you MainActivity must be running to open the second Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Intent i = new Intent("com.ex.intentdemo.Action_myown");
        startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

Remove *finish()* from your code. Current activity will go to pause state automatically. Let the activity behave normally as long as you don't want it to.